# IPhone SDK handling calls

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any way to handle call events in iPhone? i.e. Log calls and sms in my app, block unwanted numbers, etc. I know the iPhone SDK doesn't provide that but I have been googling this and what I got was an app called iBlackList. Although it runs on jail-broken phones but it does my required functionality. I wonder how? Has anyone idea about how these tasks can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through private APIs. (Which means that such application will never make it to the AppStore.)

Comment: Can you please Name one of them? and their usage if possible. Thanks

Comment: @zoul The app he mentioned is on the app store. no idea whether it works or not